# Не отображаеться расширение в результатах поиска vs code

Tags: visual-studio-code

Пишу в поиск расширений "e​CSStractor" - не выдаёт его, аналогично с "scss formatter", при этом при поиске на сайте `marketplace.visualstudio.com` [данное расширение](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=diz.ecsstractor-port) имеется. Стоит последняя версия `VSCode` `1.64`. Такая же проблема в форке `VSCodium` версии `1.62.3`. Так же при копировании команды с сайта выше, где расширение есть и вставке его в окно `Ctrl + P` мне предлагает выполнить поиск и тоже не находит. Почему так?

UPD: частично решил проблему для себя скачав с `marketplace.visualstudio.com` `vsix` файл и установкой его в vs code и vscdium.

Answer (score 0):

В **VSCodium** отображаются не все расширения, сам если честно не знаю почему. Раньше пользовался им, но из-за проблемы с плагинами решил вернуться в обычный **VSCode**. И вам рекомендую использовать обычный **VSCode**, но это уже ваше решение.

> **Цитата**
>
> Пишу в поиск расширений "e​CSStractor" - не выдаёт его, аналогично с "scss formatter", при этом при поиске на сайте marketplace.visualstudio.com данное расширение имеется.

А вы не пробовали установить через сайт? Там есть кнопка **"Install"** и она как раз таки перекинет вас в **VSCode** с помощью magnet-ссылки. И уже потом начнется сама установка. Также не исключено, что проблема может быть в самом **VSCodium**, ибо еще раз повторюсь, что там присутствуют проблемы с плагинами.

**UPD:** Только что проверил установку через ссылку, все работает. В VSCode плагин нашелся и спокойно установился.

Comment: В VSCode тоже не находит нужные плагины. Через кнопку install на сайте оно кидает в редактор и спрашивает найти ли плагин, по нажатию enter оно вбивает поиск и так же не находит его.